# Projective geometry - How to compute a Plücker matrix from a camera center, direction vector and rotation matrix?

Tags: projective-geometry

for a homework assignment I am supposed to compute the intersection between two lines in 3D. One of them is defined by the camera center, a direction vector and rotation matrix.
Unfortunately, I don't understand how I can get the Plücker matrix line representation from that.

Plücker coordinates are defined as $L = (q, q')$ where $q$ is the direction vector of the line and $q'$ the plane normal (of the plane defined by the origin and the line) as far as I know.

But I have no idea how this would work with the information I have. Could anyone please give me a hint?

Comment: Convert the Cartesian coordinates of the camera center and direction vector into homogeneous coordinates.

Comment: apologies, I still don't get it. What do I do with these then? Can I get another point that lies on the line with these somehow?

Comment: Why do you need a rotation matrix?

Comment: The Plücker _matrix_ of the line through points $\mathbf p$ and $\mathbf q$ is $\mathbf p\mathbf q^T-\mathbf q\mathbf p^T$. The camera center and direction vector are your two points. Plücker _coordinates_, while related to the matrix, are something else.